# Prove that any solution of the system x′ = f(t,x) can be extended indefinitely if |f(t, x)| <= k|x| for all t and all |x| >=r, r, k > 0.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:

Prove that any solution of the system x′ = f(t, x) can be extended
indefinitely if |f(t, x)| <= k|x| for all t and all |x| >= r, where r, k > 0.

Can someone help me out with this problem?

I am guessing that Comparison theorem and also another theorem which I have posted here will work. I tried solving using comparison theorem but I am not able to get the exact result. That's why I need help in this. Please help!!

[image][image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without some other conditions it is not clear how you can get existence let alone uniqueness.

Comment: What other conditions do you need to solve this? I know that x' = f(t,x) is given means x(to)=x0. This is the IVP which we need to consider while doing this problem. I will still ask my prof about this doubt or concern which you raised right now. Thanks!!

Comment: I figured a way, we can use Comparison theorem: Let F(t,v) be continuous and |f(t,x)| ≤ F(t,|x|). Let φ(t) be a solution of the system x' = f(t,x) and v(t) be the solution of the scalar equation dv/dt = F(t,v), v(to) = η with |φ(to)| ≤ η. Then |φ(t)| ≤ v(t) for all t≥ to. I was also wondering if we can also use f(t,x) =A(t)x + h(t) which is continuous on |R. Then we have global existence for the solution of the I.V.P. x' = f(t,x) with x(to)=xo. Please let me know if this helps. 
.